# Will Looking at the monitor for a long time affect eye sight

Tags: display, work-environment

I sit at the computer for more than 20 hours per day. when I work on my computer for longer hours I get tears in my eyes also headache and dizziness. I was just wondering if it will affect my eye sight if I look at the monitor for a long time. If yes then what type of monitor is good .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any type of monitor, experts recommend taking "eye breaks" every 1-2 hours at a minimum.  This would normally involve changing your visual range (look at something far away) or in a different lighting situation.  Since you should also be taking mental breaks, and breaks for your hands if you type/click a lot, it's wise to combine.  For me, at least every 2 hours I:

- Get up from my desk.
- Stretch/wriggle hands and fingers.
- Take a walk down the hall and back.

This can be a bathroom break, trip to the lunch room, get some water, whatever.  But you need to get up and away from the screen for 5 minutes or so.

Also, it's better for your eyes if you have decent lighting.  A dark room with a bright screen is especially hard on the eyes, but you also don't want direct light causing a glare or making the screen hard  to see.

Comment: where should the light be behind the user or in front of him ?

Comment: Overhead is probably best.  If the light is behind you may get a glare, if the light is ahead of you it may be behind the monitor and give you backlighting, which makes it harder to see.

Comment: Small fonts also put unnecessary strain on your eyes.